# SED remove spaces and line breaks

Tags: text-processing, sed, xml

I have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:enabled="false" android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@id/action_container"
          android:background="@null" android:paddingLeft="4.0dip" android:layout_width="0.0dip"
          android:layout_height="48.0dip" android:layout_weight="1.0"
          style="@style/Widget.Compat.NotificationActionContainer"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ImageView android:enabled="false" android:layout_gravity="start|center" android:id="@id/action_image"
           android:layout_width="@dimen/notification_action_icon_size"
           android:layout_height="@dimen/notification_action_icon_size" android:scaleType="centerInside"
           android:alpha="0.5"/>
<TextView android:enabled="false" android:textColor="#ffcccccc" 
          android:ellipsize="end"
          android:layout_gravity="start|center" 
          android:id="@id/action_text" android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
          android:clickable="false" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:singleLine="true" android:alpha="0.5" 
          style="@style/Widget.Compat.NotificationActionText"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm trying to remove the extra spaces and line breaks.

This is the result i need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:enabled="false" android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@id/action_container" android:background="@null" android:paddingLeft="4.0dip" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="48.0dip" android:layout_weight="1.0" style="@style/Widget.Compat.NotificationActionContainer" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ImageView android:enabled="false" android:layout_gravity="start|center" android:id="@id/action_image" android:layout_width="@dimen/notification_action_icon_size" android:layout_height="@dimen/notification_action_icon_size" android:scaleType="centerInside" android:alpha="0.5"/>
<TextView android:enabled="false" android:textColor="#ffcccccc" android:ellipsize="end" android:layout_gravity="start|center" android:id="@id/action_text" android:paddingLeft="4.0dip" android:clickable="false" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true" android:alpha="0.5" style="@style/Widget.Compat.NotificationActionText"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried using this command

```
sed -i '' 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' file.xml
```

It removed some spaces, but didn't remove the line breaks.

Eventually i want to be able to change for example the ImageView's width (android:layout_width) to 5dip by knowing only its id(@id/action_image).

i want to be able to get an xml element by it's id and change the value of it's other parameters

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Any XML parse would treat the two variations of the data as identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `xmlstarlet` and its `fo` command:

```
$ xmlstarlet fo file.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:enabled="false" android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@id/action_container" android:background="@null" android:paddingLeft="4.0dip" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="48.0dip" android:layout_weight="1.0" style="@style/Widget.Compat.NotificationActionContainer">
  <ImageView android:enabled="false" android:layout_gravity="start|center" android:id="@id/action_image" android:layout_width="@dimen/notification_action_icon_size" android:layout_height="@dimen/notification_action_icon_size" android:scaleType="centerInside" android:alpha="0.5"/>
  <TextView android:enabled="false" android:textColor="#ffcccccc" android:ellipsize="end" android:layout_gravity="start|center" android:id="@id/action_text" android:paddingLeft="4.0dip" android:clickable="false" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true" android:alpha="0.5" style="@style/Widget.Compat.NotificationActionText"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Use `xmlstarlet fo -n` to omit the indentation completely.

---

To modify the `android:layout_width` attribute of the `ImageView` node whose `android:id` attribute is `@id/action_image`, you definitely do not need to reformat the XML document:

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -u '//ImageView[@android:id="@id/action_image"]/@android:layout_width' -v "5dip" file.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:enabled="false" android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@id/action_container" android:background="@null" android:paddingLeft="4.0dip" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="48.0dip" android:layout_weight="1.0" style="@style/Widget.Compat.NotificationActionContainer">
  <ImageView android:enabled="false" android:layout_gravity="start|center" android:id="@id/action_image" android:layout_width="5dip" android:layout_height="@dimen/notification_action_icon_size" android:scaleType="centerInside" android:alpha="0.5"/>
  <TextView android:enabled="false" android:textColor="#ffcccccc" android:ellipsize="end" android:layout_gravity="start|center" android:id="@id/action_text" android:paddingLeft="4.0dip" android:clickable="false" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true" android:alpha="0.5" style="@style/Widget.Compat.NotificationActionText"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here we use `xmlstarlet` to edit the correct attribute of the node we're after. The attribute is selected using the XPath expression

```
//ImageView[@android:id="@id/action_image"]/@android:layout_width
```

The `//ImageView` in the XPath expression will look for `ImageView` nodes *anywhere* within the document.  To restrict it to only child nodes of the top-level `LinearLayout` node, use `/LinearLayout/ImageView` instead.

The `-v "5dip"` in the command gives the attribute the new value.

Strictly speaking, the question says

> i want to be able to get an xml element by it's id [...]

i.e., without knowing the node's name. To do that, just change `ImageView` in the XPath expression to `*`.  That way you'll update *all* nodes whose `android:id` matches the given string.

Related:

- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)
   (on StackOverflow)

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` to change the separators and truncate 2 or more whitespaces to one:

```
$ awk -v RS="<" -v FS="\n" -v ORS="\n" -v OFS=" " '$0 {$1="<"$1; gsub(/  +/," ",$0); print}' input.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

The `awk` solution which includes a change of `layout_width` to `5dip`:

```
awk -v RS='> *\n *' -v ORS='>\n' '/id="@id\/action_image"/{gsub("layout_width=[^ ]*","layout_width=\"5dip\"")}NF=NF' file
```

It works in this particular case, but in general these standard linux tools are not suited for processing xml files.

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:enabled="false" android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@id/action_container" android:background="@null" android:paddingLeft="4.0dip" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="48.0dip" android:layout_weight="1.0" style="@style/Widget.Compat.NotificationActionContainer" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ImageView android:enabled="false" android:layout_gravity="start|center" android:id="@id/action_image" android:layout_width="5dip" android:layout_height="@dimen/notification_action_icon_size" android:scaleType="centerInside" android:alpha="0.5"/>
<TextView android:enabled="false" android:textColor="#ffcccccc" android:ellipsize="end" android:layout_gravity="start|center" android:id="@id/action_text" android:paddingLeft="4.0dip" android:clickable="false" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true" android:alpha="0.5" style="@style/Widget.Compat.NotificationActionText"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

One quick hack for this limited html code is the following:

```
$ perl -F'(?m:^<|>$)' -0777 -ane '
   pop @F;
   print $_, qw[< >][$|--] for map { s/\n\h+/ /gr } @F;
   print "\n";
 ' input.html
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:enabled="false" android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@id/action_container" android:background="@null" android:paddingLeft="4.0dip" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="48.0dip" android:layout_weight="1.0" style="@style/Widget.Compat.NotificationActionContainer" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ImageView android:enabled="false" android:layout_gravity="start|center" android:id="@id/action_image" android:layout_width="@dimen/notification_action_icon_size" android:layout_height="@dimen/notification_action_icon_size" android:scaleType="centerInside" android:alpha="0.5"/>
<TextView android:enabled="false" android:textColor="#ffcccccc" android:ellipsize="end" android:layout_gravity="start|center" android:id="@id/action_text" android:paddingLeft="4.0dip" android:clickable="false" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true" android:alpha="0.5" style="@style/Widget.Compat.NotificationActionText"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

using the `sed` editor also we can perform the same:

```
$ sed -e '
   /^<.*>$/b
   /^</,/\/\{0,1\}>$/!b
   H;/^</h;/\/\{0,1\}>$/!d;g
   s/[[:blank:]]*\n[[:blank:]]*/ /g
 ' input.html
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try with below command to remove extra spaces and blanklines

sed -r "s/+//g" filename|sed '/^$/d'

Comment: Did you try this command?